# Is there a way to find where a private IP/domain points to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that site I was given makes use of ElasticSearch. I know it connects to ElasticSearch via a private IP (domain). I can see this IP in EC2 console in Network Interfaces. The Status column says, "in-use," but no instance ID.  What's the deal? Is there a way to find out where ElasticSearch is running? I haven't been given SSH access to the EC2 instances yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears they have Elasticsearch Service. [That's](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=917153) where ElasticSearch is running.

Comment: Yes, if you're using a managed service like ElasticSearch, ElastiCache, RDS, Aurora, etc., you won't be given SSH access. AWS manages the actual servers; you just get an endpoint to use.